# How to define cacheable in XML for second level cache in jpa

Tags: java, caching, annotations, jpa-2.0, xml-configuration

I have an entity which I want to enable caching for in one scenario but to disable it in another.
For this reason I want to define the caching not via annotation but via a configuration file.
What I'd like to know is what and where do I need to write in order to have a "foo" entity cached?
Additionally I'd like to know if there are any repercussions to defining this via the config file other than the caching (for example if this involves defining the entity itself in a tag does this set some defaults etc).
Thanks
**Update**
I found the relevant part in the [spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf) (12.2.3.3).
I'll try it tomorrow and if so post an answer with a snippet for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spring? If you can upgrade to Spring 3.1, just define 2 different methods in you DAO and annotate the method you want by @Cacheable.

Comment: Hi, I'm using spring and not 3.1 yet but in any case this doesn't feel like the solution to me since in the system where I want cache I don't want to leave any "loopholes". Additionally I think annotations are great but they should not contain any deployment dependent information. Once I saw this could be deployment dependent I want to switch to external configuration.